# Renaming Dataframe columns by position

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I am working with several large data frames which contain the same columns in each position so **(df1$1 = df2$1 = dfn$1)**. However, these columns have different names.

How I would write a function or loop which renames the first column  **"..1"**, the second column **"..2"** until the final column n which is **"..n"**?

Comment: Are those the names you want, `"..1"`, etc? Would something like `"X001"`, etc do it?

Comment: That would also be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can rename your df with vector of column names

```
df=data.frame(x=1,y=2,z=3)
df
  x y z
1 1 2 3

names(df)=paste0("..",1:ncol(df))
df
  ..1 ..2 ..3
1   1   2   3
```